# In which countries a medically unfit US pilot can fly?

Tags: medical, international, regulations

For example can one get another license in a foreign country?

Which countries allow that?

Comment: As long as the medical condition isn't disqualifying in the other country then why not? The US can't tell other countries who they can or can't give a license to. It's hard to say more than that without more information.

Comment: of course in many (most?) countries the medical requirements are actually more strict than they are in the US...

Answer (score 6):

It completely depends on the condition. Just because you're denied a FAA medical it doesn't automatically mean you can't get one to operate in another country.

For example, colour-blind pilots can fly up to First Officer level in Australia, and we have no mandatory retirement age. But we are stricter on things like head injuries.

Answer (score 5):

It's possible. One example: Bob Hoover [got an Australian license and medical certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob_Hoover#End_of_career) while his US medical was revoked.