# If a pilot license is revoked by a country's aviation authority, can the pilot still obtain another license?

Tags: regulations, airline-pilot

There was a recent new story of a Kuwait Airways pilot that got his license revoked after an investigation into an incident on an international flight where unauthorized persons were allowed on to the flight deck.

You can read more about the actual incident [here](http://gulfnews.com/news/gulf/kuwait/kuwait-airways-pilot-loses-licence-for-inviting-porn-star-into-cockpit-1.1631938).

Can this pilot still obtain another license to fly commercially?

Comment: [Related](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/9643/62)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the regulations in force. Usually, depending in the reason for revocation, the pilots can apply for recertification after a set period (usually one year) where they have to go through the whole process again. For example, according to [14 CFR 61.13](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/61.13),

> (d) Application during suspension or revocation.
>
> ...
>
> (2) Unless otherwise authorized by the Administrator, a person whose pilot, flight instructor, or ground instructor certificate has been revoked may not apply for any certificate, rating, or authorization for 1 year after the date of revocation.

It appears that these pilots too, can get another certificate after an year. According to [Kuwait Civil Aviation Safety Regulations, Part 1](https://www.dgca.gov.kw/en/safety-systems/aviation-dept-and-systems/aviation-safety-department/kcasr),

> 1.2.11 Surrender, Suspension or Revocation of License, Certificate or
>   Authority
>
> ...
>
> 3) Unless the order of revocation provides otherwise, a person whose
>   License/ authority /certificate is revoked, may not apply for any
>   License, certificate or authority before the elapse of one year from
>   the date of revocation.

Comment: In this document, the term _certificate_ means license?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid In case you're  asking about the FAA document, the terms are used interchangeably. The KCASR, on the other hand specifically mentions both though I think it that here too, they are interchangeable.